# How do I install wayland and use it?

Tags: wayland

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux-WCpNvRFM) video.  How do I get Weston on Ubuntu to try it?

Where can I find other desktop environments that work with wayland - are there any wayland ports for it like GNOME and KDE?

Comment: This link maybe help https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wayland and also this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wayland` is in [Official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wayland&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all). You can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install libwayland0
```

---

Also visit : [Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/base/wayland) for Repository & PackageHead information.

Comment: So, to use Wayland, install that library.... and then what?

Answer (score 1):

[For 18.04, Ubuntu has Wayland installed but not enabled by default.](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/01/26/bionic-beaver-18-04-lts-to-use-xorg-by-default)

To enable it follow the directions here [18.04: How to get Wayland back after upgrade to 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1033004/477026)

> On the login screen, you should be able to select "Ubuntu on Wayland" by clicking on the settings icon, next to the login button.