# Running Wayland on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xorg, wayland

I recently installed 18.04, and would like to try out Wayland in place of Xorg. As far as I can tell, I should see a drop down from the cog at login, but I currently only see:

```
Ubuntu
Ubuntu Communitheme on Xorg
```

I'd like to see options for Wayland. I looked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033004/18-04-how-to-get-wayland-back-after-upgrade-to-18-04) but the file looked fine, and had the `WaylandEnable=false` line commented out. I also tried in recovery mode with the same result. It did not work. A final note: I usually use Ubuntu with Communitheme on Xorg. If I could use Communitheme and Wayland, that would be optimal.

Comment: I seems to recall that if you don't see wayland as an option after you have enabled it with `WaylandEnable=true`, it may mean that you video driver doesn't support it. Try a different video driver?

Comment: Wayland does not work on all video drivers (ie NVidia), and will not be available in such cases.