# Install wayland on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, wayland

How can I install/use Wayland on Ubuntu 19.04. There is no possibility to select Wayland on the log-in screen, so I guess it is not installed. Also, on Ubuntu 19.04 there is no package `libwayland0` in the package manager that I could install.

I would like to use Wayland to be able to use different scaling on two different screens.

Comment: Wayland and Xorg are BOTH installed by a stock 19.04 Desktop .iso. Did you install stock Ubuntu? Or did you install a different flavor, or make any customizations? [Example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033004)

Comment: Xrandr allows you to scale monitors individually, but I haven't had a need to try it.

Comment: You should respond to 1st comment above & ck. example.. As far as "libwayland0", there isn't nor ever has been such a package in Ubuntu. See here list of packages, https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/disco/wayland  4 should be default installed, i.e, -client0, -server0, -cursor0, -egl1

Comment: Yes, it is stock Ubuntu 19.04 desktop. The mentioned wayland packages were installed. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the 4 wayland packages and now the gear shows up and I can log in with Wayland. Thank you for your help!

Comment: can confirm ubuntu 19.04 ships without a wayland login option and is not on wayland by default.